# navigation using kinect without laser scan

Tags: ros, navigation, kinect, 2d-image, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm new for ROS. And nowadays, I'm thinking about how to let my robot avoid obstacles and navigation only use a Kinect. I find a video in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmnepqAQIlk
I wonder if there are some important and useful information that you can tell me.

Thanks first.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211192/navigation-using-kinect-without-laser-scan/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A really nice node called [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/pointcloud_to_laserscan) is used to create a fake laser scan from a kinect's point cloud. It is actually better than using a lidar in some cases since it doesn't just look at a single slice of space, but rather a swath that is defined using the max_height and min_height parameters. Once you have that fake laserscan, you can use it as input to any of the navigation algorithms that are meant for lidars. (I've never used this node, so I'm assuming this is what it does).

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2015-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-06-12**:
Thank you, pointcloud_to_laserscan is really a good choose . But I don't know how to use it, I use another package named perception_pcl instead. This package could work correctly, but its'  status is not good as there are few laserscan points.